# Dynamic dictionary name in templatetag

Tags: django, templatetags

I have a templatetag to get the dictionary name and the element in it. I have the dictionaries in `dictionary.py` and I've imported the same as dict in the templatetag. Like this,

```
import property.dictionary as dict

def getlisttype(value,arg):
    return dict.value[arg]
```

I'm passing the dictionary name as value and the element in it as arg. But what I'm getting is an error saying no 'value' in dictionary. Is there a way to do this?

**dictionary.py**

```
list_type_dict={
1:"Sale",
2:"Rent"
}

list_category_dict={
1:"Residential",
2:"Commercial"
}
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) which is a dictionary of all attributes in a module, i.e.:

```
import property.dictionary

def getlisttype(value, arg):
    return property.dictionary.__dict__[value][arg]
```

It is not a good idea to import your module as `dict` since that will cause a name conflict with the built in `dict` keyword.